# Spring boot - Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xstream

I'm getting the error when upgrading to Boot 2.0 and updated XStream libraries:

```
Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
```

I've found other info out there, but not much related to Spring boot. I'm using an XStreamMarshaller to marshal some objects. Any advice on how to get rid of it?

Environment: Spring boot 2.0 and XStream 1.4.10

I have the following marshaller bean:

```
@Bean
public XStreamMarshaller sparkyMarshaller() {
    Map<String, Class<?>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("Sparky", Sparky.class);

    XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xstreamMarshaller.setAliases(myMap);
    xstreamMarshaller.setSupportedClasses(Sparky.class);


    return xstreamMarshaller;
}
```

Which I then autowire into business logic. Elsewhere it says to set the permissions, but haven't had any luck with doing that. Anyone have an example of how this may work?